# IntentService using ThreadPoolExecutor... recommended or not?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice, executors

I'm designing an android app that will listen to the incoming SMSs and will handle them in a specific way.
I have a broadcast receiver that receives the message and sends it to an intent service:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, SMSIntentService.class);
serviceIntent.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

The purpose of the intent service is to save the SMS to my own DB and then send that message to a server via HTTP POST, evaluate the result and update the app's DB and eventually reply to the sender.
So far everything is good but as there is a chance that a lot of SMS arrive at the same time, I want to decouple the communication with the server putting it in another thread.

So what I'm doing so far is this:

```
SmsDto sms = smsDataSource.saveSms(new SmsDto(originator, body, timestamp));

SMSProcessingTask task = new SMSProcessingTask(this.getApplicationContext(), sms);
Thread t = new Thread(task);
t.start();
```

And so far so good, but I don't trust this implementation with a big amount of messages.

So, my question is:

In an intent service, is it recommended to use a ThreadPoolExecutor?
I would end up with something like this:

```
//in IntentService's onCreate
this.executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

//in onHandleIntent()
executor.execute(task);
```

What happens if for a period of time no messages are received and the IntentService stops. Will the threads created by it continue running?

I don't know if this approach is the best way to deal with what I'm trying to accomplish.

Thanks

Update:

- There is not UI activity at all in this app.
- Since the communication with the server can take quite a long time, I want to minimize the processing time of a message, so the next sms in queue is picked up quickly and start being processed.

Ni

Answer (score 0):

No you shouldn't use one. The main reason being that SQlite access is not thread safe so you don't want multiple threads writing to the database at the same time.
Also, if you task happens to update the UI it's not going to work that way.

I really don't understand why you have those tasks : the IntentService already processes its messages off the UI thread.

Comment: I've read here that if the access to the SQLlite DB is singleton, it's thread safe. Besides I'm not updating the same message. 

The intentService has a queue, and if a message takes n seconds to process for whatever reason, the next in line will start being processed after those n seconds. That's what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the submit(Callable) method instead of the execute one.

that way you can get a future object with the data you want to write in the DB and no thread will actually touch it as it not safe like Phillippe said

I used it on a similar way when I needed multiple httprquests to send.
I managed them using SQL DB, so the writing only occur on the onHandleIntent.

```
while(helper.requestsExists()){
        ArrayList<String> requestArr = helper.getRequestsToExcute(3);
        //checks if the DB requests exists
        if(!requestArr.isEmpty()){
            //execute them and delete the DB entry
            for(int i=0;i<requestArr.size();i++){
                file = new File(requestArr.get(i));
                Log.e("file",file.toString());
                Future<String> future = executor.submit(new MyThread(file,getApplicationContext()));

                Log.e("future object", future.toString());
                try {
                    long idToDelete = Long.parseLong(future.get());
                    Log.e("THREAD ANSWER", future.get() + "");
                    helper.deleteRequest(idToDelete);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e("future try", "");
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    executor.shutdown();
```

secondly the intentService will not stop until the onHandleIntent is done and even if so, the threads will continue running until they've done their job